# Magento2: How can solve two shipping option selections in estimated shipping?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I have added two shipping options and getting price in estimated shipping section in cart page. but when I select one shipping option then it is selecting both option. I need one selection at a time as default work. please check attech screenshot:

[image]

Please find my code where I am calling both shipping options in

> /app/code/Mageplaza/MyModule/Model/Carrier/Carrier.php

```
 public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

     $shippingPrice = 0;
     $premiumshipPrice = $shippingPrice+15;

     $shippingPrice=(float)$shippingPrice;
     $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
    $methodship= array( "Standard Shipping", "Premium Shipping");
    foreach($methodship as $mship) {  
            if($mship == "Premium Shipping")
            {
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            $method->setMethod($this->_code);
            $method->setMethodTitle($mship);
            $method->setPrice($premiumshipPrice);
            $method->setCost($premiumshipPrice);
            $result->append($method);
            }else{

            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            $method->setMethod($this->_code);
            $method->setMethodTitle($mship);
            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);
            $result->append($method);
            }
            }
                return $result;
        }
```

please let me know If I am missing something here, Kindly help me for this.

Comment: maybe try to use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: like this if($mship === "Premium Shipping")

Comment: which shipping is in your `$_code` ?

Comment: @magefms I have tried with === but still getting both option selection. Can you please check again.

Comment: please post your $_code value

Comment: @magefms I am using custom shipping "postnet" in $_code

Comment: Sorry I have print $_code value then it is "clicknship"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89759/discussion-between-ravi-varma-and-magefms).

Comment: @RaviVarma set the group name to `Radio Button`.

Comment: can you show your js an phtml file?
names can be the same  also group name should be radio button